# Redirecting grep to a file in the directory of search causes infinite recursion

Tags: bash, recursion, grep, io-redirection

I'm trying to search the current directory recursively for the string `$level`. I want it to redirect the output to a file called `tmpfile2.txt`. When I try to do this, with

```
grep -nr '\$level' . > tmpfile2.txt
```

the file `tmpfile2.txt` grows without bound. The culprit seems to be that grep starts searching tmpfile2.txt and adding what it finds in tmpfile2.txt *to* tmpfile2.txt, so it recurs infinitely.

Odder still, it seems I did this successfully not more than an hour ago, with a nearly identical command. The only difference was that it was `tmpfile1.txt` and there was no dollar sign in the search string. However, I just tried it without the dollar sign and it's still giving me the same problem.

My questions are a) how can I solve this and b) is this the standard behavior of grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude `tmpfile2.txt` in `grep` command:

```
grep -nr '\$level' --exclude=tmpfile2.txt . > tmpfile2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could redirect the grep output into a file located outside the folder being searched.

Comment: This is a much simpler and probably better idea. Thanks.